# BigQuery: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword LEFT

Tags: google-bigquery

I got this error of "Syntax error:  Unexpected keyword LEFT" from the following SQL (standard SQL) in BigQuery:

```
select left(cast(ts as string), 16) from temp.loc limit 1;
```

"ts" is a timestamp field and I wanted to get upto minutes of timestamp. Any idea?

Comment: Just running "select left('this is a test', 5)" generats the same error.

Comment: This query should be working from what I can see.  Maybe include some sample data to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You see my very basic example above in the comment section. This happens from Big Query console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left isn't a function in Standard SQL. Try using substr instead

[SUBSTR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#substr)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the minutes from a `timestamp` field, use `EXTRACT` - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract_1

```
EXTRACT(minutes from ts) as minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for how to get the left-most characters in a string:
Use LPAD instead of LEFT.

Example:

```
SELECT 
  LPAD('Hello', 3)
```

returns 'Hel'